# Proper JavaScript code

Tags: javascript

What is the proper way to write JavaScript functions/indent code:

This:

```
function sample() {

}
```

Or this:

```
function sample()
{

}
```

Also, what about spaces, this:

```
( arg1, arg2 )
```

Or this:

```
(arg1, arg2)
```

What about this:

```
() {
```

Or this:

```
(){
```

This is what I prefer:

```
function sample(x1, x2) {

}
```

Comment: Its your choice... select which one is more **readable for you**.  While writing code you can have spaces *whereas while deploying its going to be minfied*

Comment: Write crappy code, stick in jsFiddle, hit "Tidy Up", and you're done!

Comment: First is usually preferred. JSLint requires the first. But no requirement, just pick one or the other always.

Comment: https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javascriptguide.xml

Comment: Neither of these are written cast in stone. It's mostly down to personal preference and the team that you are working with, as you will see from most of the answers you get on here.

But something to consider apart from readability, is that if you go with option one as compared to option with coding large scripts, your script will take up less space, and therefore save a few bytes here and there, not a massive difference to the application but every little counts.

Makes absolutely no difference when minifying though.

I think the most important thing is to feel comfortable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since JavaScript is a C-style language (syntactically derived from Java), [all the known coding styles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style) from those worlds are possible. Choose one yourself.

If you're working on a project with other people, you should agree on some [coding conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coding_conventions).

Common and influential ones (from larger projects) are:

- [Node.js style guide](https://github.com/felixge/node-style-guide)
- [Crockford's code conventions](http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html)
- [Google JavaScript Style Guide](https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javascriptguide.xml)
- [Mozilla coding style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Developer_Guide/Coding_Style) (language-agnostic)

See also [*JavaScript Style Guides And Beautifiers*](http://addyosmani.com/blog/javascript-style-guides-and-beautifiers/) by Addy Osmani.

---

> I prefer this: `function sample(arg1, arg2) {`

That's indeed the most common style.

Answer (score 1):

You can use whichever one you feel looks better and is easier to follow. Personally I prefer to put the opening brace on the same line as the function call, with a space between them. This makes it have a nice block without any extra white space.

For parameters I usually use `(x1, x2)`
But that's just my personal preference. Really, just take your pick.

It is important, however, to try to follow a generalized format if you work at a company that shares a lot of code. I try to match the pattern of other files in my project so that jumping from one file to another doesn't give you wildly different layout conventions.

Answer (score 0):

Both are proper. It is a matter of personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

There's no such thing as "proper" style. There are plenty of style guides. Follow one and be consistent. If you want your code to be easily adoptable, follow a popular style guide.

Answer (score -1):

I (and most others) personally like the first one.
Reason:

It is cleaner / Easy to read.
Otherwise both format will execute perfectly in the same way.